# why .net core web api methods require HttpMethodAttribute to map to respective request type Get/put/post/delete

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 projects

***One is in.NetFramework 4.8***

**WebAPi SampleController Controller**:

```
namespace Samples.FrameWork.Mvc.Controllers
{
    public class SampleController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Sample
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

***Other is in .NetCore 2.2***

**WebAPi SampleController Controller**:

```
     namespace Samples.NetCore.WebApi.Controllers
     {
            [Route("api/[controller]")]
            [ApiController]
            public class SampleController : ControllerBase
            {
                // GET: api/Sample
                [HttpGet]
                public IEnumerable<string> Get()
                {
                    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
                }
            } 
  }
```

so.. in Dot NetFrameWork the actions will act based on the name

for the above example have

methods name as

```
  Get(){}
  Post(){}
  Put(){} 
  Delete(){}
```

when above methods are requested based on the request type it will automatically map 
to respective method.

but when it comes to .net core web API
it also works but with the help of HttpMethodAttribute.

**my question is why does .net core web API methods do not work without HttpMethodAttribute as it works in .net framework?**

Comment: I had a quick check and this behaves the same in .NetCore 3.1 LTS